# Strange behavior with dynamic char ** in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, realloc

I used to code in C a long time ago and I seem to have lost my chops.

I am experiencing some odd behavior with a dynamic `char *` array. I have a curses window (implemented in another file) that is to display a list of strings of active CU and TTY devices on my local machine. I attempt to zero-initialize a `char **` array with `calloc`, and then grow it by one appropriate size each time (`dir->d_name`) matches my string comparisons.

The problem is that these strings display half the time upon running the program, and the other half of the time they are garbled or blank.

I suspect this is a memory/pointer issue related to either `malloc()` or `calloc()`, but I have been unable to pinpoint my misunderstanding for several days. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcs.h"
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define arraysize(ar) sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0])

int main(void) 
{
    char ch;
    const char tty[4] = "tty.";
    const char cu[3] = "cu.";
    const char *directory = "/dev/";
    const char **devices = calloc(0,sizeof(const char *));

    // Initial device list gen //

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir; 
    int count=0;
    d = opendir(directory); 
    if (d != NULL)
    {
        while((dir = readdir(d)))
        {
            if(strncmp(dir->d_name,tty,4)==0 || strncmp(dir->d_name,cu,3)==0)
            {
                count++;
                devices = realloc(devices,(count+1)*sizeof(const char *));
                devices[count-1] = (dir->d_name);
            }   
        }
        closedir(d);    
    }
printf("\n%d\n",count);

struct display MAIN = screen_init();

// Display List //

list_devices(devices,count,MAIN.devpad);
while(ch != 'q')
{
    ch = getch();
}
endwin();
}
```

Thank you for your time/attention.

Comment: Why are you allocating zero of something? That makes no sense. Using `realloc` is pretty messy here. Why not allocate in larger chunks to avoid hammering the allocator so frequently?

Comment: Is it not the same as setting the pointer to NULL?

Comment: You probably should set it to `NULL` until you're prepared to allocate something. You might find a simple linked list is a better way of storing all this data, you can append nodes easily without reallocating.

Comment: It's also not clear why `devices_fixed` even factors in here. What purpose does that serve when you already have the memory allocated for them in the first place?

Comment: Your absolutely right ... that was my attempt at debugging and I appear to posted the wrong version. I apologize. Everything before that is the same, and normally, devices is passed to my drawing function. The suggestion of linked lists is a good idea though, thanks!   Edit: I have updated the code above to the intended version.

Comment: The entry pointed to by `dir` ceases to exist (at least, as far as your program is concerned) after a call of `closedir()`.  Your code is keeping the address `dir->d_name`, and using it after calling `closedir()`.

Comment: Thats right. I think I had a brain fart and forgot that -> deals by pointer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem here is that you're not copying the `dir` `d_name` buffer. As the manual says:

> The data returned by `readdir()` may be overwritten by subsequent calls to `readdir()` for the same directory stream.

This means you need to explicitly copy it:

```
devices[count-1] = strdup(dir->d_name);
```

That should eliminate a lot of the garbling.

Comment: Thats it! I knew it was something silly - I should have paid more attention to my usage of readdir() instead of cobbling it in like that. Your swift help is very appreciated - Thanks!  Edit: I'm unable to upvote your answer.

Comment: No trouble! Always pays to read the documentation on any function carefully. There's usually some thorny gotcha.